# How to check the paragraph start of equation?

Tags: vba, ms-word

There is the paragraph which is like

> a =a_1 (x ̃_B [n]+x ̃_W [n] )  ------ equation 01

How can I know it is start of equation via word vba?

There is equation shape when the cursor stop at the equation.

But I can't get the shpae when I use Range class.

Comment: So that we can try to reproduce what you're experiencing could you please describe how to insert the equation - just to be sure we're doing it correctly. And please also tell us the version of Word you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Find the first OMath object in the paragraph.

2.Compare with the start position of the paragraph.

```
Dim OMathStart as Long
OMathStart = -1
if ThisDocument.Paragraphs(100).Range.OMaths.Count > 0 then
    OMathStart = ThisDocument.Paragraphs(100).Range.OMaths(1).Range.Start
end if
If OMathStart > 0 and OMathStart = ThisDocument.Paragraphs(100).Range.Start then
    'Mean the Paragraph's Start position is same as OMathStart
end if
```